# fedora 34 installation error "initramfs unpacking failed : xz-compressed data is corrupt"

Tags: fedora, initramfs, iso

I have this problem with fedora 32,33,34 beta,34 bootable iso my laptop(Acer 5741 core i5,4f ram,250gb ssd), "failed to start iscsi userspace i/o driver" , "Refusing to continue " and "system halted" :( ,
I use rufus and fedora-mediawriter for creating bootable flash disk on some of my flash memories,

I put an image in attachment about it .

The main error seems is this :

```
"initramfs unpacking failed : xz-compressed data is corrupt"
```

I checked iso checksum`(sha256sum is ok)` and change my USB flash , and none of them solved my problem ! the funny thing is I tested on another laptop and boot with out any problem!
why?! any idea?

[image: fedora 32 boot error]

Now in fedora 34 that i tested, The error goes to kernel panic page :
[image]

Comment: If the "Fedora 32 bootable ISO" is actually named `Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-32-1.6.iso`, I just downloaded it and checked the initramfs files (both UEFI and classic BIOS boot versions) and they seem to be OK. Exactly how are you writing the ISO image to the USB drive?

Comment: This USB stick may malfunction in your laptop.

Comment: @telcoM thanks, yes , Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-32-1.6.iso

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I use this usb stick for booting another iso (debian ir ubuntu) and everything is fine , but with this specific iso i have problem , and i use another flash memory and problem still persist .

Comment: Might be a CPU/RAM/BIOS issue as well.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov how can i find out ?! i use rufus for write on flash memory.

Comment: still have this problem on new release fedora 34 :(((